# Showing all Full Hours on X-Axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

Python Beginer here. I have a `.tsv` file with data like this:

```
Date         Time        Day     Sales
2020-08-07  17:20:04    Friday   37
2020-08-07  17:30:05    Friday   38
...and so on
```

I would like to plot this. I've tried this:

```python
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
import datetime
import pandas as pd


series = read_csv('data.tsv', sep="\t")
pyplot.figure()


x = pd.to_datetime(series['Time']).dt.time
y = series['Sales']

pyplot.plot(x,y)
pyplot.show()
```

It works! However, I'd like to show every hour of the day on the x-axis. I've tried doing:

```python
times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i), '%H') for i in range(24)]
pyplot.xticks(times)
```

... but it doesn't work. Right now it seems quite random whats on the x-axis (00:00, 05:33:20, 11:06 ...)

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks! I get: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.dates' has no attribute 'AutoDateFormatterDateFormatter'`

Comment: Sorry I don't want to be annoying, but I now get `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'locator'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code.  `AutoDateFormatter()` sets an automatic format. `DateFormatter('%H:%M')` set hours:minutes as format.

See [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator) for more options, both for the locator and for the formatter.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = pd.date_range(start='2020-02-14 20:30', end='2020-02-14 22:20', freq='7min')
series = pd.DataFrame({'Time': times,
                       'Sales': 20 + np.random.uniform(-1, 1, len(times)).cumsum()})
x = series['Time']
y = series['Sales']

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
# plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]